# How to get type of cdata of pypy cffi?

Tags: python, pypy, python-cffi

```
>>>> a = ffi.cast('int', 10)            
>>>> <cdata 'int' 10>
```

I want to know the type of the value of 'a'.
I've typed 'dir(a)' kind of things, but I cannot find any method to do it.
I want a function like below

```
>>>> gettypeofcdata(a)
>>>> 'int'
```

But I'm not sure if pypy's cffi has this kind of function.
Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Have you tried type(a)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `ffi.typeof(cdata)`.  You have further attributes on the `CType` object that you get, if needed.